# .htaccess 301 redirect from no trailing slash to .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In `.htaccess`, I'm trying to redirect a URL with no trailing slash to a URL with a `.php` extension.

It seems that the issue is that the page name is the same, as the style of 301 redirect I'm using works when the page name is different between the starting URL and the redirected URL.

Using the 301 redirect below, I get an redirect loop error.

```
RewriteRule ^example http://www.example.com/example.php  [R=301,L]
```

How can I make this 301 redirect work? I tried first redirecting to a different page, and then redirecting again to the final URL with no luck.

At the top of `.htaccess` is

```
AcceptPathInfo off
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression ^example matches both `example` and `example.php`.

Because you are using a 301 redirect, a request from the browser for `example`. Gets a response telling the browser to visit `example.php`. However the second request for `example.php` also matches the RewriteRule and generates another 301 redirect.

Update the regular expression to only work on the `example` request.

```
RewriteRule ^example$ http://www.example.com/example.php  [R=301,L]
```

The trailing $ tells the regular expression engine that the match ends at that point and there must be no additional characters in the request string.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Interesting about the $ and regular expressions; I have a lot to learn.